# Question of difficult matrix problem, minimum number of times

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, extremal-combinatorics

There is a $n$×$n$ matrix $A_n$. All entries are $0$ at first.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$

The example of $5$×$5$ matrix at an initial condition.

Next, you choose m numbers $b_1, b_2, .. b_m$. $(1 \leq b_k \leq n)$ Then, entries $a(i,j)$ will come to $1$. $(i,j = b_1, b_2, .. , b_m)$

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$

The example when $n = 5 ,m = 3$ and you choose $b_1 = 1, b_2 = 2, b_3 = 4$.

I want to make all entries into $1$ in the minimum number of times for $n, m$. I call this minimum times $F(n,m)$. Please solve for $F(n,m)$.

Examples:
$F(n,n) = 1, F(n,2) = n(n-1)/2, F(4,3)=3, F(7,3)=7$

I know $
  \lceil n(n-1)/m(m-1) \rceil \le F(n,m)$

Comment: Please use latex, your question is almost impossible to read. See here for a tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Soryy, I'll rewrite it.

Comment: Are the entries which become $1$, randomly chosen ?

Comment: Why not let $m=n$ and $b_1=1,b_2=2,\ldots$

Comment: I'd like to choose $b$ to minimize the number of times.