# Photo Booth problem

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

There are $n$ people.
There is a Photo Booth in which they can enter at most $m$ people at one time.
They want to get a picture with all other person together.
Please solve the $F(n,m)$; minimum number of times to get required pictures.

For example, there are people: $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$, and a Photo Booth in which they can enter at most $3$ people at one time. When they form a group $\left\{ A, B, C \right\}$, $\left\{B, C, D \right\}$ and $\left\{A, C, D\right\}$, $A$ can get pictures with $B$, $C$ and $D$ ,etc. In this case, $F(4,3)=3$

See also [Question of difficult matrix problem, minimum number of times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089637/question-of-difficult-matrix-problem-minimum-number-of-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $(v,k,t)$ covering is a family of subsets of $\{1,2,3\dots v\}$ such that each subset has $k$ elements and every subset of $\{1,2,3\dots,v\}$ that has exactly $t$ elements is contained in one of the subsets of the family.

What you want to find is the minimal subsets that can be in a $\{v,k,2\}$ covering. [Here](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html) is a repository of such coverings.

Comment: Thank you!!! We're struggling in this problem for ages! I didn't know such a theory.

Comment: Yes, the case when $k=3$ has been much more extensively studied, The problem can be solve optimally when $v$ is congruent to $1$ or $3$ mod $6$ and it requires $\frac{v(v-1)}{6}$ subsets. This is called a steiner triple system.

Comment: Thank you! Isn't there an explicit general expression for $A(v, k, 2)$?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/192058/covering-designs-of-the-form-v-k-2)

Comment: Dan Gordon migrated the La Jolla covering design repository to [his new site](https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/), so it might be a good idea to update your link.