# the upper bound of covering $\{46,26,2\}$ or $\{47,26,2\}$

Tags: combinatorics

As to $\{v,k,2\}$ covering, can you show the upper bound of $A(46,26,2) = 6$ or the upper bound of $A(47,26,2) = 6$?

See also [Photo Booth problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089811/photo-booth-problem/1089824?noredirect=1#comment2223295_1089824)

Comment: Do you need $(46,26,2)$ and $(47,26,2)$ coverings of size $6$?

Comment: I need only the value. My purpose is to prove that best possible covering of $A(45,25,2) = 6$. I know the upper bound of $A(46,25,2) = 6$. If I can get the upper bound of $A(46,26,2)$ or $A(47,26,2) = 6$, I can prove the best possible covering of $A(45,25,2) = 6$. However, I couldn't find the value of $25 < k$ on the Internet and solving it by brute-force way has too much calculation amount.

Comment: when you say brute force do you mean with computer?

Comment: Yes. I think it's almost impossible for ordinary computers.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to work on this, but I don't think I'll be able to arrive at anything today. I'll post something tomorrow.

Comment: I'm really thankful to you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I won't be able to do it today, is it urgent? I need to get access to the computers at my university to read the paper saying how to produce the coverings, but that will probably have to wait until next week. I though it was open but it wasnt.

Comment: No problem, I'm not in a hurry. I'm glad if you try it when you have free time. Thank you.